# How to remove the border behind the button?

Tags: android, android-layout

There is a grey border behind my app button, how can I remove this?

I defined the `ImageButton` like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
    android:src="@drawable/library_blau_2" />
```

Comment: ensure your background doesn't have the border.

Comment: try this::  `android:background="@null"`

Answer (score 95):

You have to use `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
    android:src="@drawable/library_blau_2"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: what if i want to change the background color?

Comment: @has19...you can define your customized style and make borderlessButtonStyle the parent...<style name="blah" parent="borderlessButtonStyle">

Answer (score 11):

try this :

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/library_blau_2" />
```

Answer (score 11):

Simple and easy way is

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change the background of your imageview to transparent as below:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" <----- Set background.
    android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
    android:src="@drawable/library_blau_2" />
```

**OR** You can only set the background then you don't need to apply the transparent color.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/download" <--- set only the background
    android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
 />
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this works just fine:

android:background="@null"

Answer (score 1):

Try this
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
in your button tab

Answer (score 0):

you can try this simple one

```
android:background=""
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?